# Joomla-like url rewrite

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, joomla

I know that similar questions were already asked, but i could not find any information for my specific "problem".
What i want to do is the following in a very dynamic way, which means that a "SuperUser" should be able to define new routes in a admin interface:

If a user enters http://www.example.com/nice-url/

he should get redirected to http://www.example.com/category.php?id=123 without changing the url.

Now there are a few ways i can achieve this. Either i use .htaccess like this:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^nice-url category.php?id=123 [L]
```

This works, but is not very dynamic. I would need to let a php script append new rules at the bottom which is not something i would like to do.

Or this:

**.htaccess**

```
 FallbackResource /process.php
```

**process.php**

```
$path = ltrim($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], '/');  
$elements = explode('/', $path);               

if(count($elements) == 0) {                  
    header("Location: http://www.example.com");
    exit;
}

$sql = sprintf("SELECT Target FROM urlrewrites WHERE Source = '%s' LIMIT 1", array_shift($elements));
$result = execQuery($sql);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
$target = $row['Target'];

header("Location: ".$target);
exit;
```

This also works, but sadly the url in the address bar gets changed. Is there a way in the middle of both? Having the flexibilty of PHP and the "silentness" of `RewriteEngine`? How do great CMS like joomla do it? Do they generate a htaccess file for each new page you create?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have this code in root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine on

# If the request is not for a valid directory
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
# If the request is not for a valid file
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ category.php?uri=$1 [L,QSA]
```

PS: Note this will route `/nice-url` to `/category.php?uri=nice-url`. Then inside `category.php` you can dip into your database and translate `$_GET['uri']` to `id`.

Answer (score 0):

It would be more dynamic if you use regular expressions. That's how it works in CMS systems like Joomla. Good idea is to install Joomla with 'nice' URLs on and look over .htacces file to get to know how does it work.
You can start here:
http://www.elated.com/articles/mod-rewrite-tutorial-for-absolute-beginners/

Comment: Well i know about regular expressions. My main question was: how do they handle additional pages, which are getting added by the user? I don't believe that they rewrite the whole .htaccess file when a new page gets added. The problem is also that i don't know the specific routes beforehand.

Comment: In Joomla it is achieved using routing mechanism which concept is described here:  https://docs.joomla.org/Supporting_SEF_URLs_in_your_component
and the overall idea is here:
https://docs.joomla.org/Routing_implementation_details

Comment: Looks like no one can clearly explain how to make it possible with plain PHP. Who has example?